# Skype Bot Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

So recently, I set up a NodeJS bot to link messages between a Discord chat and a Skype chat. Now, I'm pretty new to Javascript, and entirely new to NodeJS, so luckily for me, there's a framework already made called [Spype](https://github.com/findel/spype). The discord side works by using Discord's bot API, so that side works totally fine. The Skype side, on the other hand, uses [Skyweb](https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/skyweb) to connect to the Skype web client. Now, that's all well and good, except that it uses actual Skype accounts to log in, and you can no longer create actual Skype accounts, only Microsoft accounts. (Those are the ones that start with "live:".) The problem is that apparently, these two account types use different login methods. Now, try as I might, I have not been able to get the REST stuff to work for the Microsoft account login. This is probably due to my lack of expertise in that area.

So either I need to get Skyweb to log in to Microsoft accounts (this is probably the easiest option, I feel like it should be easy, I just can't get it), or change the bot to use a totally different authentication system.

I really hope someone can help with this. Let me know if I left out any information.

Comment: Skyweb now supports Microsoft accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skyweb has been updated, the issue has been fixed.